# Verifying a formula for the $k$th derivative of a function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\Omega \subset \Bbb R^N$ be open and $f:\Omega \to \Bbb R^n$ be smooth.

For $a \in \Bbb N^N$, let $|a| = a_1 + \cdots + a_N$ and $a! = a_1 ! \cdots a_N !$. Also, for such an $a$ and for a $\xi \in \Bbb R^N$, let $\xi^a = \xi_1^{a_1} \cdots \xi_N^{a_N}$.

Define:

$$\partial^a f = \frac{\partial^{|a|} f}{\partial x_1^{a_1} \cdots \partial x_N ^{a_N}}$$

I need to prove the following:

$$f^{(k)}(x) \xi^k = \sum_{|a| = k} \frac{k!}{a!} \partial^a f(x) \xi^a$$

Where $f^{(k)}(x) \xi^k$ denotes the application of $f^{(k)}(x)$ to $\xi$ $k$-times.

For $k=1$, this is evident. For $k=2$,

$$f' = \begin{pmatrix} \partial_{x_1}f_1 & \cdots & \partial_{x_N}f_1 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \partial_{x_1}f_n & \cdots & \partial_{x_N} f_n \end{pmatrix}$$

How to find $f''$ or how to write it in some compact form in order to expand $f''(x) \xi^2$ and try to see why this should satisfy the above formula?

Comment: How exactly are you defining $f^{(k)}(x)$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair: $f': \Omega \to \mathcal{L}(\Bbb R^N, \Bbb R^n)$ is the derivative map of $f$, and $f''$ is the derivative map of $f'$, so $f'': \Omega \to \mathcal{L}(\Bbb R^N, \mathcal{L}(\Bbb R^N, \Bbb R^n))$, and so forth.